# Iterating through list of lists of class objects, returns that object is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have an initial class:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

And another class which uses the foo class:

```
class bar:
    def __init__(self, foos):
        self.foos = sorted(foos, key=attrgetter('a'))
```

where `foos` is a list of `foo`. I now want to take a list of list of `foo`, something that looks like:

```
lofoos = [[foo1, foo2, foo3], [foo4, foo5, foo6] ...]
```

and I want to use the map function to do this:

```
list(map(lambda foos: bar(foos), lofoos))
```

But this returns the error:

```
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'foo'.
```

Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with the complete traceback.

Comment: It's quite simple: `foo` is not an iterator.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to make bar an iterator?

Comment: it work for me...

Comment: You seem to have a broken `__iter__` implementation somewhere in your codebase.

Comment: @TimRomanski you can make `bar` an iterator *by implementing `__iter__`*, but without more context it's hard to say precisely where your problem is.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you're given `bar` individuals `foo` instead of a list of `foo`s, a well placed print reveal the problem

```
from operator import attrgetter

class foo:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
   def __repr__(self):
      return "{0.__class__.__name__}({0.a},{0.b})".format(self)

class bar:
   def __init__(self, foos):
      print("foos=",foos)
      self.foos = sorted(foos, key=attrgetter('a'))
   def __repr__(self):
      return "{0.__class__.__name__}({0.foos})".format(self)

lofoos = [[foo(1,0), foo(2,0), foo(3,0)], [foo(4,1), foo(5,1), foo(6,1)]]
print("test list of lists of foo")
print(list(map(lambda foos: bar(foos), lofoos)))
print("\n")
print("test list of foo")
print(list(map(lambda foos: bar(foos), lofoos[0])))
```

output

```
test list of lists of foo
foos= [foo(1,0), foo(2,0), foo(3,0)]
foos= [foo(4,1), foo(5,1), foo(6,1)]
[bar([foo(1,0), foo(2,0), foo(3,0)]), bar([foo(4,1), foo(5,1), foo(6,1)])]


test list of foo
foos= foo(1,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(list(map(lambda foos: bar(foos), lofoos[0])))
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    print(list(map(lambda foos: bar(foos), lofoos[0])))
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.foos = sorted(foos, key=attrgetter('a'))
TypeError: 'foo' object is not iterable
>>>
```

remember that what `map(fun,[a,b,c])` does is produce `[fun(a),fun(b),fun(c)]`

So in some place in your code you end doing a map in a list of `foo` instead of a list of list of `foo`

Comment: Thanks for the tests, they helped a lot in finding the problem!